# Pop Up A Page In ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to pop up an ASP.NET page using the modal popup AJAX control in ASP but in vain.

Can anyone guide me how to do that using AJAX tool kit, and if it can't be done as the modal pop up only pops up panels, how can I pop up a new ASP.NET page?

Comment: Would you post a bit of code for what you have so we can see what is not working?

Comment: Actually i don't have any code I'm just wondering if it is possible to popup an asp.net page instead of panel...if it is possible please give me a simple example that can help.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

if all you need is to launch a popup see [here](http://riderdesign.com/articles/Opening-popup-windows-in-ASP.NET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnClientClick in your server control like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="window.open('Popup.aspx',null,'height=250, width=250,status= no, resizable= no, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no ');" />
```

For "AJAX" type of modal popup, can you give more details about your problem?